# Android Emulator/Phone Google Play Services 9.8.79 return null object

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-location-services

I included play-services-location-8.4.0 in my android project,to fetching location coordinates, and on my android emulator/mobile play-services version is not same as I include in project (version 9.8.79), and location object return null and after update emulator/phone google play service version from 9.8.79 to 10.2.1 or 11+ it works fine.

Comment: if your device has a newer version it should be fine. if the device has an older version you shouldnt be able to connect the GoogleApiClient

Comment: Or if both have same verion

Comment: same version should be fine

Comment: my app version is 8.4 and emulator version is 9.8, according to you location object is not null but it always return null

Comment: according to me, if the emulator has play services version 9.8 and your app depends on version 8.4 you are able to connect the GoogleApiClient. who said anything about location objects? maybe you should express your question more clearly

Comment: my app google play service version 8.4 and emulator/mobile google play service version 9.8, which is newer version than app google play service but it returns null location object

Comment: i think that your problem is not related to google play services version, i would suggest to change / ask a new question with relevant code

Comment: When I update emulator/phone google play service version, then it works fine, and after that I uninstall google play service update then location object null

Comment: so let's recap, your app depends on 8.4. if the emulator has 9.8 location is null but if you update the emulator google play services (to 11.something?) it works?

Comment: Yes! it works fine

Comment: ok so please update your question with this information and also add the code you're using